# How to fix Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I click on the Upload button I get this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

This happens when I click on the Upload button. I am using a `fileSeletedHandler` with event arrow function:

```
  fileSelectedHandler = event => { 
      this.setState({ selectedFile: event.target && event.target.file && event.target.file[0] }) 
    }
```

Which works fine, where issue comes in is when I click on the upload button. I am using a `fileUploadHandler` with an arrow function like this:

```
  fileUploadHandler = () => {
      const fb = new FormData();
      fb.append('image', this.state.selectedFile, this.state.selectedFile.name);
    axios.post('http://localhost:5000/business/uploadFile', fb)
    .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
    })
  }
```

Where did I go wrong with my code?

Comment: try to console.log(event.target && event.target.file && event.target.file[0]) berfore the setState, and console.log(this.state.selectedFile) before the fb.append

Comment: what the jsx code for the file input looks like ?

Comment: <div className='form-group'>
                        <label>Upload file:</label>
                        <input type='file' onChange={this.fileSelectedHandler} />
                        <button onClick={this.fileUploadHandler}>Upload</button>
                    </div>

Comment: Ok I have an answer for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So according to the doc ([here](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html#the-file-input-tag)), there's a special thing with `<input type={'file'}/>` which makes that it can't be used as a controlled component.

The solution is to use a `Ref`.

So it would be like so :

```
constructor(props) {
   super(props)
   this.fileInput = React.createRef()
}

fileUploadHandler = () => {
    const fb = new FormData()
    fb.append('image', this.fileInput.current.files[0], this.fileInput.current.files[0].name)
    /* ... */
}

render() {
    return (
        /* ... */
        <input type='file' ref={this.fileInput}/>
        <button onClick={this.fileUploadHandler}>Upload</button>
        /* ... */
    )
}
```

No need for `setState` then.

Comment: i would also like to ask how do  i bind the function to display in my data list.